# Calculate text layout with StaticLayout without allow word-wrapping

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there some way to use `StaticLayout` without doing automatic word wrapping? If the text includes newlines I want them to break up the paragraphs, but I don't want it wrap at a given width.  It's not giving sane results, especially with Center/Right aligned text.

Is there a way to simply turn off the auto-wrapping on `StaticLayout`?

More details. I use `getDesiredWidth` to calculate a width and then use this as the wrap width for a new `StaticLayout`. This prevents auto-wrapping, but it also seems to turn off explicit wrapping as. `GetLineCount` returns 1 for text that actually has multiple-lines.

Comment: maybe you can replace all spaces in the text with non-breaking spaces (\u00A0), but keeping linebreaks. does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Biggemot That's a good idea. I'll see if I can get non-wrapped lines that way instead.